# Why have I had 3 comments deleted on a post with no explanation whatsoever?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-comments

Why have I had 3 comments deleted on a post with no explanation whatsoever?

Here is the question: [How can I see the Progress of an JS Algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261742/how-can-i-see-the-progress-of-an-js-algorithm)

Comment: Without knowing what those comments contained we can't possibly know. Comments can be removed for any number of reasons.

Comment: @ivarni: yes that is true for most, however I believe mods *can* see deleted comments so this question can still be answered. And obvious the person that deleted it will know

Comment: I guess I should have made my question less complicated, already got 5 people that seem to be struggling to understand it...

Comment: Yes but if you want to address the mods directly you can raise a custom flag instead of asking the entire community. Or just reply and @ the mod involved in the comments in the post you linked to.

Comment: @ivarni: I can't flag because the comments don't exist anymore. And there was a mod that also commented in the post, but I asked them and they just deleted that comment to... which is a great example of what we wan't from moderators (sarcasm)

Comment: Maybe your comment aren't usefull for the content, they are chatty, etc ... so they are deleted, it's a common situation

Comment: By the way there is a Moderator involved in the discussion so am pretty sure it's him who done this, ping him

Comment: @TemaniAfif: It was deleted almost straight away. My comment was aimed at the OP and the OP didn't even get a chance to decide if it was useful or not. Why do mods think they can just make decisions for other people? If the OP didn't like the comment I am sure they can complain or flag it themselves. It's very frustrating that just because one mod doesn't understand my comment that they think nobody else will

Comment: @musefan your first comment was directed at the OP and was telling 'em in a rather non-polite way they should really consider a career change. The other two comments were you lashing out at a mod demanding to know why your comment was deleted... It's fair to say - they certainly didn't need to stay as comments.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I did ping that mod, and my comment asking him why was also deleted with no explanation.

Comment: I don't know the full context of your missing comments but at least as far as *"Why do mods think they can just make decisions for other people?"* it's because we as a community elected them to do so.

Comment: @musefan you expected a reply to: *I assume that was you that deleted my comment? Mods around here are getting to be a bit of a joke these days. Oh, and if you need me to spell it out... that isn't an insult aimed at you* instead of a mod just deleting it and not engaging you further? I can't see where you're asking for clarification and wish to discuss it in a civil manner anywhere in there...

Comment: @JonClements: The first comment was not intended to be offensive. Believe it or not there are some people in this world who are able to have a grown up conversation that involves criticism without feeling the need to get offended. The second comment was simply asking why my comment was deleted... there was nothing wrong with that one at all. And then the 3rd comment was an attempt to try and word my first comment in a more delicate way, and had no mention of career change at all... so care to try your explanations again?

Comment: @JonClements: If you can see my comments then can you please edit them in this question so other users can see examples of things that will get deleted

Comment: @ivarni: Doesn't make it right to just mass delete without the decency to explain why.

Comment: @JonClements: Also I noticed you have visited another recent [post where I commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261284/how-to-learn-communication-between-microservices). I am sure some mods would have found those comments to be "offensive" too, but as you can see the OP was able to non be offended for no reason and was able to have a discussion where he took some useful knowledge away... who would have thought hey, not everyone is the same

Comment: @musefan there's a distinct difference in the tone of comments used though. Anyway - deceze has answered your question. If you can't see what the differences are or why the comments were removed - I'm not sure what I could possibly say to help you. I'm off - see you around maybe.

Comment: @JonClements: Maybe the fact I can't see the difference should be sign enough that it's just text, and there is no "tone" or intent attached. Yes, I know I am the type of person that just says it as it is, there are a lot of us in the world. Perhaps you should be more accepting rather than judging.... PEOPLE ARE DIFFERENT, GET OVER IT

Comment: @JonClements: And `"I assume that was you that deleted my comment?"` is the part where he would say "yes, because...". Do i really need to write everything like I am talking to a child that struggles to understand words?

Comment: @musefan Yes, and some people that are different from you think what you're spouting is rather aggressive and doesn't belong here…

Comment: People are people and have feelings. If you're going to condescend or talk down to people unnecessarily then I'm going to get *involved* not *get over it*. If you can't see the difference then perhaps it's time to consider not commenting.

Comment: Perhaps this should be migrated to https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @deceze: So let them say it themselves. If someone says "I take offence to that" then I can try to explain that I didn't intend anything offensive and help them understand how I am trying to help. I just don't get why mods think they can just make these assumptions for someone else...

Comment: That's what mods do. They moderate. They moderate for tone and behaviour. And they're telling you, repeatedly, you're tending towards unwanted behaviour. You can justify it for yourself any way you want, but we're *telling you.*

Comment: @JonClements: Yes people have feelings, but not everyone takes everything personally or with emotion. There is nothing a 'nobody like you' could say to me that would hurt my feelings. And I am NOT special, if I can use the intend without attaching emotion then there are others out there that can too. Soe of us can just see comments for what they are, an unemotional opinion. Yes, some will get offended, in which case they can say something and I will tell them it wasn't intended as an insult

Comment: Put all that aside. If nothing else, nobody wants to wade through a morass of comments over career choices while they're trying to clarify the contents of a technical problem!

Comment: @deceze: Only that you didn't tell me did you? I have to create this post to find out for myself. But you know what you are right, I am not active on stack overflow because of any other reason than to help people. If you mods wan't to go around telling me what is helpful and what isn't (even though you have no business assuming on another persons behalf) then you are right. I will reduce my involves. Obviously non of you will care (and that DOES NOT offend me in the slightest by the way), my contributions are only a drop in the ocean.

Comment: @deceze: Yeah, that's a fair point, they have a task at hand to do and there is a good chance they want to focus. But maybe they have been considering a career change for a long time already and are just waiting for that one last push to make the life changing jump (for better or worse), but who knows? Certainly not me or you...

Comment: You are again jumping to uncharitable interpretations first. Again, I was *not* going to clarify this issue in that comment thread, for stated reasons. You have posted this question here *2 minutes* after it happened, not even waiting for any other sort of contact.

Comment: @deceze: What you going to do, give me a phone call? I do what I know to get a response. If comments don't work then take it to meta, which did work. So I got what I was after

Comment: I was gonna come by your house with a beer, but now that this is already settled… ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @deceze: Haha, very good. At least I got a smile out of all this in the end...

Comment: @ivarni - I did flag for that (disappearing, not overly snarky comments) and was told "declined - this is not what flags are for".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your comments were:

> @Drakeless: Well, that's what being a programmer is about. Learning how to solve problems and doing research. programming is NOT asking other people to do the work for you. If that is the life you are looking for then I suggest a career change... if you get to a point where you need to learn C++ to solve a problem, well, then you best start learning C++ – musefan 24 mins ago

After removing that one:

> @deceze: I assume that was you that deleted my comment? Mods around here are getting to be a bit of a joke these days. Oh, and if you need me to spell it out... that isn't an insult aimed at you – musefan 21 mins ago

> @Drakeless: A programmer job is to solve problems by doing research. It is best that you attempt your problem yourself, rather than expecting others to do it for you. – musefan 19 mins ago

This kind of content has absolutely no place on this site. If you can't *help* someone constructively, at least say nothing. Telling someone to consider a career change is **not helping**. Comments are ephemeral by nature and there's no expectation that they must remain forever, or even for a short time. I'm also not going to elaborate that point in the comments to an unrelated question. You further have been contacted before about similar issues, so I'm not sure into how much more detail I am required to go there.

Comments are for talking about the question or answer with the goal of improving it, *not* for berating people about their life choices nor about unrelated chatter.

Comment: Sorry, but explain why giving career advice is **not helping**? Are you saying it is better for somebody to have a huge misunderstand of what programming involves and that blinding carrying on down a specific path is a good life choice? Someone less closed-minding than you would be able to think to themselves that "ok, maybe programming involves a lot of research and that isn't something  that I personally like doing, so perhaps I should consider that programming isn't the right choice for me".. stop assuming everyone thinks the same way you do.Let the OP tell you what they think instead.

Comment: I don't know what you do for a living or even as a hobby, but let's assume you are _not_ very skilled at wood working but really want to learn it. The first day you manage to break off the saw. Your teacher/mentor/friend/whatever tells you "Well, guess you better not do this and look for a different kind of work." – If you don't see what's wrong with that, I'm not sure I can explain it to you.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, I myself make awful analogies too (it's not easy). You are comparing ability with effort there though, so doesn't really work. The question was demonstrating that the OP isn't willing to put the effort in to do there own research. It's a key part in development and really isn't something you can overlook if you wan't to be a *good* programmer. If the question showed effort and code with an error (like breaking the saw) then I wouldn't say you have the wrong career. I would either help fix the code, or move on if I don't know a solution.

Comment: There are lots of ways to help people, and criticism can be very helpful if you are willing to listen to it instead of just getting offended. So why not just let the person I am talking to decide how they want to take it? And if they flag or complain then by all means have an opinion and delete it. Remember, people ask question because they wan't the opinions of the whole community, not just the opinions of the mods

Comment: That's something that comes up again and again and I keep making this point: *you cannot prove "effort"*. OP clearly did *something* before asking the question or they wouldn't have mentioned `requestAnimationFrame`. They were on to *something*, but they didn't know enough to know where to go next. (Giving the charitable reading here.) Telling them to go get another career isn't getting them down the right path to where they know enough to continue their research.

Comment: Well that's my point... you can't really prove anything. And that is why I always argue that we should let the person that the comments are directed at to decide. Only they know what they are thinking or how they feel, pisses me off that people keep thinking they can make assumptions on other people behalf

Comment: *You* are clearly making some assumptions about what OP did or didn't do, and you're jumping on the uncharitable interpretation and are berating them for it. Assuming OP *did* attempt some honest research before posting and simply got completely stuck, they would be entirely justified in being pissed off. And nobody here wants SO to be a site where you get pissed off. So let's not always assume the *worst* of people first.

Comment: I am just going to accept the answer as you have explained why you deleted them (regardless if I agree with you or not, I got an explanation). You guys just carry on doing whatever you want...

Comment: Cheers. Here's hoping that *you* won't. ;-P